# Android dynamic button with more value

Tags: java, android

I have arrayList {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, I only want to display 4 button 1,2,3,4 each time, then if user click next it will remove previous 4 button and display 5, 6, 7, 8.  
  
 
Example:       
  1  2  
  3  4

**when user click next button** 
 
 
 4 6 
 
 7 8

 
 **when user click next button**
 
9

Here is 2x2 display method

```
    private void dynamicBtnDisplay() {
    try{
        for(int index = 0; index < 4; index++){
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById( R.id.buttonLayout );

            int buttonsInRow = 0;
            int numRows = table.getChildCount();
            TableRow row = null;
            if( numRows > 0 ){
                row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt( numRows - 1 );
                buttonsInRow = row.getChildCount();
            }

            if( numRows == 0 || buttonsInRow == 2 ){
                row = new TableRow( this );
                table.addView( row );
                buttonsInRow = 0;
            }
            if( buttonsInRow < 2 ){
                ToggleButton bb = new ToggleButton( this );
                row.addView( bb, 300, 200 );
                bb.setText(myArr[index]);
            }
        }

    }catch (NullPointerException e){

    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you are using gridview to manage this case will be better for you.

Comment: How do I remove the previous text by using gridview if user click next ?

Comment: GridView.clear() .  or you can also manage this thing using your array managment.

Comment: I still don't get how using gridview will solve my problem. Let say if I have array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, I only want to display 3 item 1,2,3 each time, then if user click next it will remove previous 3 item and display 4, 5, 6. does that make sense ?

Comment: that depends on your requirements actually.

Comment: if you want to re-use these first shown views then you can take fragments help. else then you can go for dynimically creating views in a linear layout.

Comment: is there example you can provide ? Thanks